# How to create grouped lineplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I want to make a lineplot which x-axis is year, y-axis is `avo_sales.groupby(['year','type'])['type'].count()` which means the count of each type per year, and the hue is type. I cannot make this work. It said `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

This data is what i want to plot

```
avo_sales.groupby(['year','type'])['type'].count()
Out[17]: 
year  type        
2015  conventional    2790
      organic         2807
2016  conventional    2808
      organic         2808
2017  conventional    2862
      organic         2860
2018  conventional     648
      organic          648
Name: type, dtype: int64
```

This is my plot code

```
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(x= avo_sales.year,y=avo_sales.groupby(['year','type'])['type'].count(),hue = avo_sales.type)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try as follows.

#### The following code will work for pandas >= 0.25

`pd.__version__` use these to display pandas version.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('avocado.csv')
df = df.groupby(['year','type']).agg(count=('type', 'count'))
# print df here to see how the columns are displaying
df = df.reset_index()
# print df here to see the difference

sns.lineplot(x="year", y="count", hue='type', data=df)
```

It will give the following output
[image]

Comment: thanks it works, but why does `.reset_index()` make it work?

Comment: Before `.reset_index()`, it has multilevel column, when we call reset_index() it became single level column. If you print the dataframe before and after dataframe, your could see the difference. If you share your sample data, I would show your the difference.

Comment: i'll just try to find out the different, thanks for explaining it to me, what does `.agg({'type':'count'})` mean?

Comment: `.agg` is to pass the fileds to be aggregated. We can give more than one filed as a dictionary `.agg({'type':'count', 'some field':'sum', 'another field'  : 'avg'})` like so

Comment: Could you share some data, so that I can try the error in my local machine ?

Comment: [this is my data](https://www.kaggle.com/neuromusic/avocado-prices) i think what causing it is the `reset_index` but if i delete it then the year in x is unrecognizable

Comment: thank you so much, very much. your answer is really helpful